# HTML table with background color and transparent image: border on bottom

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I'm making a horizontal menu of buttons that need to have a background color behind them. The button image is a white box with a transparent circle in the middle where the color shows through.

The actual button image will be more complex, so I can't just code the button.

This method works fine with the image width set in px. But when I set the image width to 100% to make everything mobile responsive, I get blue borders on the bottom edge of each button.

And sometimes on the other edges too: [Screenshot example from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YIRy.png)

Here's a JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/3e4xv37d/#&togetherjs=tatfPi7B6n

Code snippet:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
body[yahoofix] body,table,td,p,a,li,blockquote {
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;
}
body[yahoofix] table {
width: 100% !important;
border-collapse: collapse !important;
}
body[yahoofix] #hidden {
display: none;
}
body[yahoofix] #hidden-2 {
display: none;
}
body[yahoofix] #hidden-3 {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td valign="top">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="480px" align="center">
       <tbody>
        <td style="background-color: blue; overflow: hidden;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8xPmSIR.png" width="100%" /></td>
        <td style="background-color: blue; overflow: hidden;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8xPmSIR.png" width="100%" /></td>
        <td style="background-color: blue; overflow: hidden;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8xPmSIR.png" width="100%" /></td>
        <td style="background-color: blue; overflow: hidden;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8xPmSIR.png" width="100%" /></td>
        <td style="background-color: blue; overflow: hidden;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8xPmSIR.png" width="100%" /></td>
        <td style="background-color: blue; overflow: hidden;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8xPmSIR.png" width="100%" /></td>
       </tbody>
                        </table>

     </td>
                    </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions. Been looking everywhere and can't find any discussions on how to make this type of image work on responsive layouts.

Comment: Why use an image at all. This can all be done with CSS.

Comment: @Paulie_D I should have clarified, the final image will be more complicated so it can't be done in CSS. This is just a temporary image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely because you are trying to divide a width by a number of items that isn't evenly divisible. Your fiddle works for me in Chrome, which makes sense because 480 / 6 = 80px, so no border. If you were to make the width 481, then you've got five cells of 80px and one cell of 81px (the cells have to be "on" a pixel). Because the images are set to 100% width, that makes the image in the 81px cell slightly taller as well, and makes the entire table row an extra 1px taller. But because the images in the 80px cells are the old height, it seems to add an extra px to the bottom padding.

All of those nested tables are going to cause problems. I would go back to the drawing board as far as layout is concerned. Why not simply have a `<div>` with several `<button>`s in it side-by-side?

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks for explaining it. But I don't think I can use divs either, because I need the menu buttons to resize for mobile. Each button needs to get smaller within the whole block, so they all fit on one line regardless of browser width. Maybe it's just impossible though.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `<tr>` tags in the table with the images, may help but just first thing I noticed. I would also add `style="display:block;"` to each of the images to make it fill out the td cell.